# Расширение google,подскажите путь истинный

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Пишу расширение.
Логика его такова: парсим DOM,ищем там цену,сравниваем с нашей заданной.

manifest.json

```js
{
 "name": "SteamStickergunBuy",
 "description": "sticker buy",
 "version": "1.0",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "icons":{
 "128":"icons/red.png"
 },
 
 "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "ThisIsGooood",
      "default_icon": "icons/red.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
   
 "background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
     "http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/*",
  "tabs",
  "background" ,
  "storage",
  "alarms",
  "notifications"
        ]
}
```

background.html

```html
<div style='display: none' id='example'>Example</div>
<script src="background.js"></script>
```

background.js

```js
var items=[
{item_id:"http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Asiimov%20%28Battle-Scarred%29",price: '35500'}, 
{item_id:"http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Pit%20Viper%20%28Battle-Scarred%29",price: '35500'},
{item_id:"http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Corticera%20%28Field-Tested%29",price: '35500'},
{item_id:"http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Corticera%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29",price: '35500'},
{item_id:"http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Electric%20Hive%20%28Field-Tested%29",price: '35500'}
];
var i = 0;
 var timerId = setInterval(function() {
 var url=items[i].item_id;
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (xhr.readyState == 4){ 
   var data = xhr.responseText;
   document.body.innerHTML=data;
   var name=document.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_item_name")[0].innerHTML;
 if(document.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_table_message").length==0){
   var market_price = document.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee")[0].innerHTML;
         var marketPrice = market_price.replace(/[A-Za-zА-Яа-я.]+/, market_price);
   marketPrice = parseFloat(marketPrice) * 100;//приводим к копейкам 
   
   if(marketPrice <= items[i].price){
   var dannie=document.getElementById("dannie");
   dannie.innerHTML=name+":"+marketPrice;
   }
   console.log(name+":"+marketPrice);
 }else{console.log("Не обнаружены лоты для данного предмета с учетом выбранных фильтров.")}
    }
  }
i++;
xhr.send();
}, 10000);
```

И popup.html

```html
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<script src="background.js"></script>
<div style="height:100px;width:200px;font-size:10px;padding:3px" id="dannie">Ѕлок с данными</div >
```

Так вот код работает. Всё нормально,но в popup.html грузится вся страница целиком(т.к. я вставляю xhr.responcetext в body).

Если же я вставлю в заготовленный невидимый div example(как я хочу,чтобы в popup выводить только результат),то выходит  ошибка(якобы равен нулл,не может найти этот div)

Как быть? как лучше всего реализовать это?. Чтобы если цена ниже,что я задал. В popup.html выходило название цена и ссылка не предмет.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вы идете не тем путем. Работа вашего расширения зависит от структуры страницы которую вы парсите, если что-то изменится, вам придется искать что и где сломалось.


Почти что первая ссылка в Google - [Price Tracking + Web API](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/community_market/discussions/0/846940249109605642/).


Вы можете получать данны сразу в JSON формате, выполняя GET запросы на адрес вида:


http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=AWP%20%7C%20Asiimov%20%28Battle-Scarred%29


Где:

**currency** - валюта. Видимо нужно будет поиграть со значениями.

**appid** - ID игры. В вашем случае это - 730 (CS:GO)

**market_hash_name** - имя элемента. Т.е винтовка AWP в вашем случае.


Хотя на форуме написали запрос который имеет еще параметр **country** со значеним **DE**.
Но его изменения вроде бы результат запроса не меняли.


Полученный ответ будет следующего вида:

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"21,82\u20ac","volume":"508","median_price":"22,--\u20ac"}
```

Где:

**success** - значение которое говорит о статусе запроса. Т.е удачно или нет.

**lowest_price** - нижняя цена за которую продают предмет.

**volume** - общее число предметов(одного вида, той же винтовки AWP)

**median_price** - средняя цена по которой был продан тот или иной предмет.


В итоге вам не нужно возится с DOM, регулярками итп.


P.S. Я с этим не сталкивался, так что могут быть не точности, но суть думаю будет такая же. Как вариант вот тут кто-то предлагает [market api](http://steammarketapi.com/), не официальный конечно.


За дополнительной информацией по параметрам запроса вам лучше обратится к Google, Steam форумам, и т п. У Steam вроде даже Wiki для разработчиков была. Поищите.

Comment: через json не получается отправить запрос с фильтрами.Например (http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=AWP%20%7C%20Asiimov%20%28Battle-Scarred%29?filter=sticker)
не пройдёт запрос.

Если что-то изменится,да придётся поправить,но я пишу только для себя,так что это 5 минутное дело.

Мне бы просто связать background и popup.
Т.е. в background парсим и проверяем,а если найдём в подходящий,то его в popup.

Всё было бы хорошо,если бы я полученный DOM не вставлял  в document.body (в другие места он не вставляется).

Comment: Можно было бы просто в popup.html подключить скрпт background.js
Всё было бы хорошо,если бы я полученное от запроса не вставлял  в document.body (в другие места он не вставляется). И получается в popup в body видна вся страница.
Куда лучше вставить полученное с запроса? что бы оно было не видно,но можно было получить "doceument.getELement"