# Background.js не видит div

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Вот код background.html:

```
<div style='display: none' id='example'>Example</div>
<script  src="background.js"></script>
```

Кусок кода из background.js:

```
var data = xhr.responseText;
var example=document.getElementById("example");
example.innerHTML=data;
```

Имеется разметка background.html
Пытаюсь вставить полученное с запроса в div,но выдаёт ошибку,якобы example=null
В отладчике пишет `"TypeError:Cannot set property 'innerHTML'of null"`

Если же вставлять `document.body.innerHTML=data` то всё работает.

Comment: Такие же проблемы с popup

Comment: `style='display: none'` пробовали убирать?

Comment: @MasterAlex да конечно,эффект тот же.

Comment: попробуйте так: `var example=document.getElementById("example"); if (xhr.status == 200) { var data = xhr.responseText;   example.innerHTML=data; } else { alert('Error'); }` Может быть у вас ошибка при получении данных и поэтому в data ничего нет

Comment: @MasterAlex в data есть. Я же написал " Если же вставлять document.body.innerHTML=data то всё работает."
То есть если просто вставлять в body,то там появляется целая страница.

Comment: а скрипт находится в шапке или под кодом HTML? попробуйте перенести его вниз

Comment: @masterAlex код находится в отдельном файле background.js а сама разметка background.html   это же расширение.

Comment: в общем, выложите весь код по порядку, скорее всего ваш JS срабатывает раньше чем браузер видит `<div id="example"></div>`, поэтому переменная  `Null`

Comment: @MasterAlex полный код тут(он работает) [Ссылочка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526142/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-google-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)